# How to select all text in JTable cell when editing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to have the editor in my editable JTables select all text in the cell when starting to edit.  I have tried a couple of things that all revolve around calling JTextComponent.selectAll() on the component that is returned from the TableCellEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent method.  None of the things I tried worked.

In my latest attempt, I altered the SimpleTableDemo class from the Swing tutorial to use a custom TableCellEditor that calls the selectAll method.  In the debugger I can see that the selectAll() method is being called, but the table still goes into edit mode without selecting the text in the cell (or perhaps the selection is being cleared before display).  That code is below.  Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;


import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;


    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        final JTable table = new SelectingTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


    class SelectingTable extends JTable {
        public SelectingTable(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
            super(data, columnNames);
            TableColumnModel model = super.getColumnModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < super.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                TableColumn tc = model.getColumn(i);
                tc.setCellEditor(new SelectingEditor(new JTextField()));
            }
        }

        class SelectingEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

            public SelectingEditor(JTextField textField) {
                super(textField);
            }

            public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
                if (c instanceof JTextComponent) {
                    JTextComponent jtc = (JTextComponent) c;
                    jtc.requestFocus();
                    jtc.selectAll();
                }
                return c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Table Select All Editor](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/table-select-all-editor/) should work for you. It is the preferred solution so you don't have to keep creating custom editors. That is the columns containing integers should only accept integers. With you current code

Your code does work partially. If you start editing using the F2 key, then the text is selected. However, when you use the mouse and double click on the cell then the second mouse event is passed to the editor so the caret can be positioned where you clicked and this removes the selection. A solution for this is:

```
final JTextComponent jtc = (JTextComponent)c;
jtc.requestFocus();
//jtc.selectAll();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        jtc.selectAll();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, camickr!  I could see that the selection was being done, so I figured that it was probably being removed subsequently.  Didn't think to put another runnable on the awt thread so that it would be executed last.  I looked briefly at your RXTable, and that looks interesting.  My goal is to provide a base table class with some properties that I anticipate using often, and I will probably end up with something very much like RXTable.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great answer. I was having a hard time figuring out why selectAll does not work. The key is to know that the last mouse click goes to the text editor and then to make sure selectAll() is called after the last mouse click is processed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Had a lot of trouble implementing it myself.

Comment: I recommend putting the call to requestFocus() in the invokeLater, it enables the text to be selected when editCellAt is called directly by your code.

Comment: @camickr thank you and for your great swing expertise.  But... 1) I can't help feeling that calling invokeLater from the EDT is a bit inelegant and 2) surely there must be some component which is receiving this second mouse click and which could intercepted/replaced by something else.  Might this be the mysterious "delegate" of a DefaultCellEditor?  Also I setClickCountToStart( 1 ) ... and the problem of the editor "cancelling" the selectAll still applies.  I'd just like a bit more understanding of what's actually happening here...

Comment: @mikerodent, Double clicking on the table invokes the editor and the code to select the text is done. Once the editor has been activated JTable then passes the mouse event to the editor. The default behaviour for clicking on a text field is to clear any selection and position the caret at that location. This code adds the code to select the text to the end of the EDT so that it executes after the MouseEvent has already been handled by the editor. Using the event queue this way is a relatively common practice. P.S. still waiting for you to accept answers from your previous questions.

Comment: @camickr - answers accepted. I'm just left wondering how difficult it would be to stop the JTable passing the unwanted mouse event on to the editor.  I did an experiment with mouse_event.consume()... but naturally it didn't work as desired...

Comment: also, from a preposterously strict concurrency point of view, you might have a problem if some other event slipped into the EDT before the selectAll was executed... eg. sthg which made the text component non-selectable... but you could put an isSelectable test in your run() no doubt

Answer (score 3):

```
public class SelectAllCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    public SelectAllCellEditor(final JTextField textField ) {
        super( textField );
        textField.addFocusListener( new FocusAdapter()
        {
            public void focusGained( final FocusEvent e )
            {
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your fix in English also?

Answer (score -1):

JTables can have many different components in a cell.  It is usually a JTextField when you are editing.  You need to firstly get the field and then select.  You can get the length of the text by working through your modal.  This code should get you started, you may want to place it within a List selection handler.  ie.

```
 ListSelectionModel rowSM = this.getSelectionModel();
 rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
       DefaultCellEditor ed = (DefaultCellEditor)this.getCellEditor();
       JTextField jf = (JTextField)ed.getComponent();
       jf.select(0, *text.length()*);
       jf.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
 });
```

Notably you will need to find the text.length().  Possibly something such as:

```
this.getModel().getValueAt(this.getSelectedRow(), this.getSelectedColumn()).length();
```

*Disclaimer* I haven't tested this code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I haven't tested your code either - I tried camickr's suggestion first, and it worked.  I already had a reference to the JTextField, but my selection was getting erased.  Putting the selectAll() call in a runnable to be executed last is what solved the problem.  Thanks again for the response.