# Java difference between anonymous subclass and regular (non-anonymous) subclass

Tags: java, reflection, overriding, subclass

I'm having trouble finding information regarding this kind of subclassing/overriding in Java, which I see used a lot in Swing applications (event listeners and stuff like that):

```
// ...  
SomeClass foo = new SomeClass() { 
@Override
public String methodToOverride() { return ""; }
}
```

vs

```
class SubClass extends SomeClass {
@Override
public String methodToOverride() { return ""; }
}
// ...
SubClass foo = new SubClass();
```

Is the first case still a subclass of 'SomeClass', or is it the same type with an overridden method? In particular, what happens in the first case if inside `methodToOverride()` I call `super.methodToOverride()`? Will it call the original SomeClass' methodToOverride(), or SomeClass' parent `methodToOverride()`?

Comment: [This Article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) may help.

Comment: thanks. Part of the problem in fact was that I did not know the name of that 'trick' (anonymous subclass, now I renamed the question as well).

Comment: @Edoz: A related example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8488735/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the first case still a subclass of 'SomeClass', or is it the same type with an overridden method?

It is a subclass of `SomeClass`. And what do you mean by - "same type with overridden method". It doesn't make sense.

> what happens in the first case if inside methodToOverride() I call super.methodToOverride()? Will it call the original SomeClass' methodToOverride(), or SomeClass' parent methodToOverride()?

It will call the method in `SomeClass`.

Basically the two approach works almost identically. You often use anonymous subclasses, when you only want to use them once. The difference is - you can't have constructors in anonymous subclasses, among others.

Comment: I just meant "or is it not a subclass". Your answer answers the question, thanks.